# Remove Session ID from Canonical URL

Tags: google-search-console, canonical-url, cookie, session

I have two URL's

```
http://www.domain.com/thread.php?1234-a-brand-new-thread/page2
http://www.domain.com/thread.php?1234-a-brand-new-thread/p=54762
```

'p' is equal to a post on the second page, so the two URL's above go to an identical page.

Both have the canonical URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/thread.php?1234-a-brand-new-thread/page2
```

However, the two URL's at the top are coming up as duplicate title tags in Search Console's HTML Improvements.

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the issue may be caused by a Session ID that gets added to the canonical URL when cookies are disabled; and I've read that Googlebot doesn't always use cookies.

So the canonical URL for a browser without cookies would be:

```
http://www.domain.com/thread.php?1234-a-brand-new-thread/page2&s=5678
```

And when another session is started, the canonical URL would be different again.

Should the canonical URL be without a Session ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canonical url tag should contain the least information possibile to identify the page.

If `http://www.domain.com/thread.php?1234-a-brand-new-thread/page2` is enough to go to that page, just put this as canonical url.

Don't forget to use the `rel="next"` and `rel="prev"` tag too.

You can even consider a "view all" page if it's easier to implement.

Check this http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.it/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html

Comment: Thanks - i figured that to be that case. I have removed the session ID now. Hopefully that will clear up any duplicate issues with Google.